# What is the mean of "to appear" in references

Tags: reference-request

I want to find the reference 21 in picture below. Then, it is French, I don't know French. Seemly, the reference 22 is like to 21, so I want to find reference 22, but what is the mean of to appear ? How can I find it ? Or there are English version of 21 ?

> [image]

Comment: It hasn't been published yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard meaning of it is: the article has been accepted, but it is not published yet.

Comment: If so, how the reader can find it ?

Comment: @lanse7pty In many cases it has a form: to appear in... In your case, you can only guess.